# ActionScript 3 Optimization - improving performance with large #'s of objects

Tags: performance, optimization, actionscript, refactoring, particles

I'm devloping some library classes for flocking/steering behaviours on large numbers of objects (2000+). I'm finding that at < 500 instances, performance is reasonable. As the numbers increase, framerate bogs down.

I've seen remarkable performance with libraries such as Flint or Box2D with ridiculous #'s of particles / objects, so it should be possible to optimize / refactor my code to be a bit better.

I'm aware of the basic optimizations, such as bitwise operations and optimized for loops. Are there any more fundamental approaches I should be considering? For example, currently each instance is a vector-based MovieClip. Would working with BitmapData be more efficient?

Comment: In short I believe you are correct about using BitmapData vs vector-based movie clips, you may even get more efficiency out of just setting cacheAsBitmap to true on your MovieClip.  Generally speaking it seems what I've gotten the largest performance boost out of in Flex/Flash is tightly controlling the creation and destruction of objects, I know this is sort of obvious but do everything you can to re-use already created objects.  Also as counterintuitive as it may seem use Number instead of uint or int as the player does a better job optimizing with Number.

Comment: Specifically I used some of these techniques when optimizing code for use with google maps flash api, more on that here http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/ I'd also recommend avoiding use of Bindable wherever possible since this has the potential to add a lot of unneeded overhead (adding the listener/dispatcher code to your AS3 for you and automatically dispatching events is costly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forget about vectors.

cache them as bitmapdata and draw to a bitmap, or draw a bitmapfilled rect to graphics.

dont use vectors. find a way around it. be clever. bitmap lookup tables, caching, more lookup tables.
spend RAM on caching things for different orientations, views, frames, etc,  rather than spending PROCESSOR on wasteful cpu cycles.

Comment: I'm working through some BitmapData experiments now. There are a ton of optimizations that are possible in this domain, though Flash Player 10.1 seems to make some of them a little unnecessary. Here's a fantastic resource / tutorial (though it's about particles, not flocking behaviour) http://unitzeroone.com/blog/2011/01/16/the-particle-sessions-part-one-is-this-it/